# How to make a Bottom Navigation bar with ImageView instead of Menu Items?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

How can I make a working **bottom navigation bar with ImageViews** in a LinearLayout(Horizontal) With fragments ?  instead of menu items.

*if already exist then please share the source code.* Please help quickly :)

Or the Question could be this :

https://github.com/qhutch/BottomSheetLayout/issues/12#issue-576279364

Comment: Why not changing the menu icons to the Image Views you want?

Comment: @AlonYeager this is not about image or icon, i want to do an operation with that icon such as rotate and toggle on a progress with the id of that icon. but when i use menu item it shows me **create an abstract as 'item_id_name'.**  so when i use it on image view it works but when i use it as menu item it do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found my solution not exactly but this is what I want...
I add that Bottom Navigation View in a LinearLayout(horizontal) and I delete all default Styles from BottomNavigationView. So now this is not looking like a card view. After this, I add an ImageView in the LinearLayout with a weight of a ratio of 1:3 (for 4 icons ). Now I can use effects and designs on my LinearLayout. And it is looking like how I wish. 
[Note: For horizontally rotated screen LinearLayout, ImageView, BottomNavigationView 's width:match-parent]